# SonarQube - automatically assign non-default quality profile/gates

Tags: sonarqube

I have the following scenario:

We have many quality gates and profiles in Sonarqube for example quality profiles:

```
Quality Profile A (DEFAULT)
Quality Profile B
Quality Profile C
```

and I would like to automatically assign new created project (**Project XYZ**) to **Quality Profile B**, but new **Project XYZ** will be assigned to default **Quality Profile A** and I have to explicitly change that.

Is it possible to define that **Project XYZ** will use **Quality Profile B**? The best solution for me will be option to define some regex (Project starting with X will be assigned to Quality Profile B)

I use SonarQube version 5.6.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to first initialise your projet with api rest command for example :

```
curl -k -X POST  https://xxx/sonar/api/qualityprofiles/add_project  --data 'language=css&profileName=CssProfil&projectKey=myProjKey'
curl -k -X POST https://xxx/sonar/api/qualitygates/select  --data 'gateId=4&projectId=myProjKey'
```

with myProjKey, when using Maven, it is automatically set to

> groupId:artifactId

Then your next code analyse will works with theses new settings

Hope this is helps you